# glibmm.h: could not find such directory or file

Tags: c++, cmake, gtkmm

I want to include gtk to my new cmake project. But wen I compile, I get this error: +

```
In file included from /home/chhu/CLionProjects/MasterMind/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h:87: fatal error: glibmm.h: could not find such directory or file
```

This is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(MasterMind)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# Use the package PkgConfig to detect GTK+ headers/library files
FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

# Setup CMake to use GTK+, tell the compiler where to look for headers
# and to the linker where to look for libraries
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# Add other flags to the compiler
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

add_executable(MasterMind main.cpp)

# Link the target to the GTK+ libraries
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MasterMind ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```

This is my class:

```
#include <gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
auto app =
        Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
                                 "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

Gtk::Window window;
window.set_default_size(200, 200);

return app->run(window);
}
```

I am developing under ubuntu 20.4. My g++ version is 9.3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gtkmm is not a part of Gtk. You should update your CMakeLists

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTKMM3 REQUIRED gtkmm-3.0)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTKMM3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GTKMM3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

ADD_DEFINITIONS(${GTKMM3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MasterMind ${GTKMM3_LIBRARIES})
```